# set a custom setup.exe/unins.exe icon in innosetup

Tags: exe, inno-setup, pascalscript

I've bumped into many posts about having a custom Icon for the `unins000.exe`. So far I understood that setting `SetupIconFile = img\unins000.ico` and then using the `[Icons]` section to set the others icon *(add/remove and app.exe)* was a way to go since the `unins000.exe` and `setupApp.exe` uses the same `.ico` set using `SetupIconFile` , but **I wasn't able to keep the `setupApp.ico` on the `setupApp.exe` and it kept having the `unins000.ico`

It feels kind of hard to work around that and it doesn't feel reliable, so I was wondering if : **Is there any way to have a diffrent icon for :**

- `setupApp.exe` as `setupApp.ico`
- `unins000.exe` as `unins000.ico`

*Here are my attempts and results so far :*

```
#define MyAppExeName "app.exe"
#define MyAppUninsExeName "unins000.exe"

[Setup]
SetupIconFile=img\unins000.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon=img\app.ico
...

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked


[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}";         Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}";          Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}";                       Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "img\app.ico"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,MyApp}"; Filename: "{app}\{MyAppUninsExeName}"       ; IconFilename: "img\unins000.ico"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}";               Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "img\app.ico"
```

so far, **this was working:**

- `unins000.exe` in folder `C:\Program Files` had  the `unins000.ico`.
- add/remove had the `app.exe` icon.

but, **this was not working:**

- `setupApp.exe` had the `unins000.ico` instead of the `setupApp.ico`.

*I hope everything is clear, if something isn't clear, feel free to bump it.*